# Special Character (~) automatically Converted into (-) when fetch (PHP, PDO, MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PDO with mysql. In my Table(table1) I have the following values.

```
+-------+-------------------+-----------------+
|   ID  |        TYPE       |      VALUE      |
+-------+-------------------+-----------------+
|   1   |   NORMAL          |   1~2           |
|   2   |   NORMAL1         |   4~5           |
|   3   |   NORMAL2         |   5~6           |
+-------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

The following code is used to fetch the value -

```
$this->dbh = new \PDO("mysql:dbname=". $this->config['db']['name'] .";host=". $this->config['db']['host'] .";port=". $this->config['db']['port']. ";charset=utf8",

 $sql   = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT VALUE FROM table1 WHERE TYPE = ?");
 $sql->execute(array("NORMAL1"));
 $cols = $sql->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 echo $cols['VALUE'];
```

Value Display Like This: 4-5. i need the exact value like this 4~5. (~) symbol automatically changed into (-). what can i do.

Comment: Make sure that your database has set the charset to UTF8.

Comment: Is your connection UTF-8?

Comment: $dbh->exec("set names utf8");

Comment: $dbh->exec("set names utf8") in which place i need add the coding @Deep